# Best way to backup and restore system image for laptop on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, backup

Currently, my method is by just using the default tool in XP:

**Backup procedure**

1. System Tools > Backup
2. Choose to backup system files to another partition or USB drive

*Now if the systen crashes sometime in the future:*

**Restore procedure**

1. Reinstall fresh Windows XP on the same laptop
2. System Tools > Backup
3. Restore system files from the other partition or USB drive

I was wondering if this is the most optimal way to backup a system image in XP?

Comment: There is no single "best" method. There's also no dearth of disk imaging utilities. Just try a few and use whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

What someone considers to be best will be an individual matter. I like to boot a system with a [Live CD or DVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) and run a backup operation using a tool on the Live CD/DVD. I.e., you boot the system into an alternate operating system, though it might even be Windows XP utilizing a tool such as [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/), which allows you to boot into Windows XP from a CD rather than the hard disk in a system. I use [Clonezilla](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/unix/linux/Clonezilla/cloning.php) and [SystemRescueCD](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/unix/linux/sysrescuecd/), which are Linux-based, though there are many such tools, some of which you may find easier to use, which give you the option of creating a system image or backing up individual [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning) on the drive. You can use them to backup the internal hard disk drive in the laptop to an external USB drive. When you need to restore the system from a backup, you connect the backup drive again and reboot from the Live CD and choose a restore option.